# How can I bind a listbox selecteditem content to a textbox?

Tags: wpf, linq, binding

I have a listbox thats getting binded by this query when TextName content changes:

```
var players =
    from p in context.Player
    where p.GivenName.StartsWith(TextName.Text.Trim())
    select p;

listNames.ItemsSource = players.ToList();
```

It shows the players names that starts with the text on the textbox. Now when I click any Item  (name) from the listbox I need that the TextName shows the player name that's selected on the listbox. I tried to bind it this way:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding Source=listNames, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" ... />
```

But when I click a ListboxItem, the textbox just get cleared and does not show anything.. may I have to set up the textbox like I do with the listbox when setting the DisplayMemeberPath???? I need a only one way binding!!
What can I do??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your binding:

1. You are using the Source property instead of the ElementName to specify the list box name
2. You are trying to bind to a Content property which (I am assuming) does not exist on your `Player` object.  This happens because the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` is an instance of `Player` when you specify an `ItemsSource` as you have

To solve this you should change your binding to the following:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding ElementName=listNames, Path=SelectedItem.GivenName}" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding ElementName=listNames, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" ... />
```

This binds the `TextBox.Text` to the ListBoxes - called listNames - SelectedItem, which contains `Player` objects, and you need its Name property.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <Page
        x:Class="Studentt1.MainPage"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:local="using:Studentt1"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          mc:Ignorable="d">

             <Grid Background="Wheat">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}" 
             SelectedItem="Binding SelectedStud,Mode=TwoWay}"         
             DisplayMemberPath="StudName"    
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="332" Margin="59,173,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"                                                                
    <Button Content="Load" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="144,567,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

            <Grid  Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="352"   
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="633">  
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="347"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="401"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="367*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="251*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  FontSize="30" Grid.Column="0" Text="Registration 
        Number" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="46,0,25,0" Width="276"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding 
        ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedItem.RegNo,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" Text="Name"  
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="144,0,124,0" Width="79"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding  
        ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedItem.StudName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" Text="Age" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="157,0,137,0" Width="53"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding 
        ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedItem.Age,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
       </Grid>


      </Grid>
      </Page>
```

here i bind the selected item of list box to text box..

you can find zip file for full source code

Comment: What ZIP file are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RelativeSource` to access the ListBox, e.g.:

```
  <TextBox ... Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                      AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" .... />
```